# add data to a many to many relationship mySQL java springboot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, api, many-to-many

i have 3 tables in mySQL, User, Institution and Role

1)one to many relation from user to institution (one user can work at one institution, and one institution can have many users)
2)many to many relation between role and user
the institutions in my database are already inserted and the user can only work in a specific existing institution.
and also the rolesin my database are already inserted and the user can only have an existing role.
i manually added 7 roles to my DB for user and for institution.

i want to add a user and specify his role in the API request but it wont work.

-------user model-------

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="user_Id")
    private int userId;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="lastname")
    private String lastname;
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name="isActive")
    private boolean isActive;
    @Column(name="lastActive")
    private String lastActive;
    @Column(name="createdDate")
    private String createdDate;
    @Column(name="isBlocked")
    private boolean isBlocked;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "institution_id", nullable = false)
    private Institution institution;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_has_role",
            joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id",
                            nullable = false, updatable = true)},
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "role_id",
                            nullable = false, updatable = true)})
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

}
```

--------role model------------

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString

@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="role_Id")
    private int roleId;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

}
```

----------institution model------------

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString

@Entity
@Table(name = "institution")
public class Institution {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="institution_Id")
    private int institutionId;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="type")
    private String type;
    @Column(name="location")
    private String location;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "institution", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<User> user;
    
}
```

--------controller-----------

```
@PostMapping("/addUser")
    public String addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        userrepository.save(user);
        return "user saved with name: " + user.getName();
    }
```

--------- my api request---------

```
{
        "name": "user1",
        "lastname": "lastname",
        "email": "user1@hotmail.com",
        "password": "user1123",
        "lastActive": "02/01/20",
        "createdDate": "06/05/19",
        "institution": {
            "institutionId": 3
            },
       "roles": [
            {
                "role_id": 2
            }
        ],  
        "active": true,
        "blocked": false
    }
```

but this is not working properly its creating a new role with empty fields...
i just need it to add into the user_has_role table the correspondent id for user_id and role_id
please help

Comment: _many to many relation between role and user_ are you sure this relationship is ok? It means that many roles can have many users and many users can have many roles. What I feel is, it should be `ManyToOne` i.e. many roles can be assigned to one user. Can you elaborate by adding some examples for roles like what can be the values for role? Otherwise it is a little difficult to understand from the DM perspective.

Comment: no it should be a many to many relationship, one user can have many roles in my case 
roles such as super-user, bank-admin, bank-support, bank-service, merchant-admin, merchant-support, merchant-service ... a user can be both a bank-admin and a merchant-admin for example...
thos are all the roles i have in my db 
i just need to assign a role to a user

Comment: You said _"one user can have many roles"_ which is a `OneToMany` relationship from `User` to `Role`. I feel you need to correct this mapping as well.

Comment: no its a many to many
also one role can be obtained by many users...
they have a joined table also... user_has_role...
i just need to know how to add a role to a user

Comment: ok, I think I get your point now...My apologies I went the wrong way I think. Let me see what I can do about your problem...

Comment: no DW! you have been greatt help!! thank you

Comment: Try adding these cascade types for `User` model under `@ManyToMany` `@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH})`

Comment: this will help me add a role to an user just like i was trying to do in my api request?

Comment: Yes, it should. Please add this, try with the request you have posted and let me know

Comment: it ddnt it has created a new empty role with role_id = 11 and it added to the user_has_role user_id=15 and role_id= 11
although i dont have a role with an id 11
it has created a new role

Comment: You have a typo in your request. Not `role_id` but `roleId`.